# Javascript (vanilla) - How to specify the type of an element when using querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

How can I specify the type of an element when using querySelecterAll()?
For example, I want to select all the input fields where type=text in a form. Not for styling but for functionality.

This is what I have right now:

```
var inputGroup = document.getElementById('contactForm');

var inputs = inputGroup.querySelectorAll("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("blur", checkInput);
}

function checkInput() {
  this.value === "" ? this.className = "error" : this.className = "valid";
}
```

Right now I am also targeting the inputs where the type is set to submit, radio etc. But I just want to target the input elements where the type is set to text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [attribute selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) directly in the call to `querySelectorAll`:

```
var inputs = inputGroup.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
```

This however may miss `<input>` tags that don't have the `type` attribute specified at all.  You can work around this by also picking up the `<input>` tags without it in your selector:

```
var inputs = inputGroup.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"],input:not([type])');
```

Comment: This is true, but it may not work if the `type` attribute is missing (in which case the `<input>` will default to type "text").

Comment: Well [yes that seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/8aLu8aww/). (In Firefox anyway.)

Comment: @Pointy Just [tested it myself](http://jsfiddle.net/q4t6bc99/) in Chrome too, thanks for the confirmation